# How to query 'classic' posts with custom field from ACF (relation field multi values)

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, relation

I need your expertise regarding a problem I have with wordpress.

Context :
I have :

Classic posts | posts
ACF | custom field applied to posts named: thematique_lien
which is a relationship field with a custom type named: Thematic

see the screen below :
[image]

My problem is that I can't make a query that retrieves :
all the posts that have in the custom field 'thematique_lien' the text 'XXX

I'm not sure if this is a good idea, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea: Value1, Value2...

Here are my query tests:

```
$args = array(
                    numberposts' => -1,
                    post_type' => 'post',
                    'meta_key' => 'thematic_link',
                    meta_value' => 'jobs'.
                );
#OR#
 $args = array(
                    post_type' => array('post'),
                    posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        'key'=> 'theme_link',
                        value' => 'jobs',
                        compare'=> 'LIKE'
                    ) )
                );
```

I've tried all over the place, but nothing works, if anyone has any ideas?

Thanks to you and have a nice day/evening ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this example based on the [ACF docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/#single-doctor.php):

```
$doctors = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'doctor',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'location', // name of custom field
            'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"', // matches exactly "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
));
```